# Struggling to avert ones eyes from what you shouldn’t see?

Tags: awrah

https://islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/160554 According to this link you can only stare at women once and other websites say that you are not allowed to look at faces of women, their hands, hair, legs and whatnot. I live in one of the most heavily populated Muslim areas in a country in the West and despite this you see women who cover properly like once every 3 months and I can actually remember the last time which shows how rare it is. Even the Muslim women else at revealing clothing and the only way not to look is to literally have your head staring right at the floor. All the women have something revealing sadly whether they are wearing loose clothes or even if they are wearing hijabs there is still something wrong. What shall I do because wherever I look there is always a women dressed wrongly and I don’t want to get sins for something I can’t avoid. Also keep in mind that I am not able to move countries

Comment: You can always move if you have a true will. Sometimes you have to pay the price if you want something better. Goodluck

Comment: Yes but I can’t I don’t have any money and as a 16 year old I don’t think I will be able to survive without any relatives either and my family don’t plan on moving anytime soon

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the spirit of the greater jihad .Not looking at women is a way for helping you win the battle but that doesn't mean that you have to continuously look at the ground and be so awkward ,you have to be comfortable in your skin ,that tension is in itself the possession of the nafs on your soul because you do it out of fear not out of understanding,if the woman is just beautiful without a hijab and not seductive for you then there will be no issue for you looking at her,it will be like looking at a flower and saying sobhanallah ,understand the spirit of not looking ,its just to help when you feel seduced till your soul becomes more mature ,till you acquire full victory over the nafs .

Good luck brother ,remmember that a Muslim can be a Muslim anywhere ,anytime.

Comment: No but the problem is that women are dressed wrongly everywhere and no matter where I look there will be one dressed incorrectly and according to the link I posted you can’t look at women like that

Comment: That is normal at the start of the greater jihad ,what Iam saying is that your not looking should be done out of conviction and not out of fear or tension ,this way you are comfortable when not looking & the nafs is not pressuring you to look.

Comment: No but let’s say there is no fear and tension for me to look no matter where I’m looking unless it’s at the sky or ground there is a woman dressed incorrectly and I can’t avoid it

Comment: Yes look at the sky or ground thats ok but without tension,don't force yourself to do it ,out of understanding you do it .Thats all Iam saying

Comment: How am I meant to walk around then?

Comment: wear sunglasses :)

Comment: I can’t tell if you are being serious or not and it is worrying

Comment: No Iam serious ,try sunglasses if they lessen the effect then that is good for you.But its impossible to keep yourself looking always up or down .You speak as if women surround you from all sides .just don't let this bug you ,also try remembering Allah while walking